# Is there a name for the two parts of a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology

A complex number is the sum of a real number and an imaginary number. Is there a collective name for the two parts comprising a complex number, such that when used, it is (pretty) clear that the context is complex numbers?

Usage example: "Write down the (two parts) of that number" - can the (two parts) be replaced by a single word?

Comment: Real and imaginary parts?

Comment: Since the individual names are *real part* and *imaginary part* it seems like calling them *the two parts* is adequate, but I don't think that is established. I'd definitely prefer "Write down the real and imaginary part of that number". Better long than ambiguous.

Comment: @GitGud - thanks. I mean, a single word. Like, "denominator" would be the number below the bar in a fraction.

Comment: @ysap Oh, I see. I believe that, by definition, the term *term* allows to be comprised of several words. You might want to replace *term* with *word* or something.

Comment: the components.

Comment: @Paul - thanks. This is definitely a good word, but my problem is that it is too generic, and not (relatively) specific to the complex numbers context.